# What is the formula to calculate the area under the ROC curve from a contingency table?

Tags: roc, auc

For example, if my table is:

```
                True Value (gold standard)
                   Positive  | Negative |
         |        |          |          |
Test     | Pos    |    A     |     B    |   
Result   |        |          |          |
         | Neg    |    C     |     D    |
         |        |          |          |
```

Comment: It's not clear to me that there can be a useful answer to this question. The receiver operating characteristic (ROC) curve represents the range of tradeoffs between true-positive and false-positive classifications as one alters the threshold for making that choice from the model.  A contingency table represents the classification results at a _particular choice_ of that threshold. One might be able to calculate something like an area (as one proposed answer here does), but it's not clear that would truly represent the area under the ROC curve for the full model.

Comment: If your predictor is dichotomous, and there is therefore only one threshold, I think the AUC still provides (some) useful information.

Comment: @JeremyMiles please provide non-trivial example of the predictor where only one threshold exists.

Comment: @PavelTyshevskyi - sure. (I forget what the context was for this question). I work with raters who classify ads. One example is pornography (which is bad). We ask raters "Is this ad for pornography?" They say yes, or no.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## In the general case: you can't

The ROC curve shows how sensitivity and specificity varies *at every possible threshold*. A contingency table has been calculated at a single threshold and information about other thresholds has been lost. Therefore you can't calculate the ROC curve from this summarized data.

## But my classifier is binary, so I have one single threshold

Binary classifiers aren't really binary. Even though they may expose only a final binary decision, all the classifiers I know rely on some quantitative estimate under the hood.

- A binary decision tree? Try to build a regression tree.
- A classifier SVM? Do a support vector regression.
- Logistic regression? Get access to the raw probabilities.
- Neural network? Use the numeric output of the last layer instead.

This will give you more freedom to choose the optimal threshold to get to the best possible classification for your needs.

## But I really want to

You really shouldn't. ROC curves with few thresholds significantly underestimate the true area under the curve (1). A ROC curve with a single point is a worst-case scenario, and any comparison with a continuous classifier will be inaccurate and misleading.

## Just give me the answer!

Ok, ok, you win. With a single point we can consider the AUC as the sum of two triangles T and U:

[image: A ROC curve with a single (SP, SE) pair and two triangles]

We can get their areas based on the contingency table (A, B, C and D as you defined):

$$
\begin{align*}
T = \frac{1 \times SE}{2} &= \frac{SE}{2} = \frac{A}{2(A + C)} \\
U = \frac{SP \times 1}{2} &= \frac{SP}{2} = \frac{D}{2(B + D)}
\end{align*}
$$

Getting the AUC:
$$
\begin{align*}
AUC &= T + U  \\
    &= \frac{A}{2(A + C)} + \frac{D}{2(B + D)} \\
    &= \frac{SE + SP}{2}
\end{align*}
$$

## To conclude

You can technically calculate a ROC AUC for a binary classifier from the confusion matrix. But just in case I wasn't clear, let me repeat one last time: **DON'T DO IT!**

### References

(1) DeLong ER, DeLong DM, Clarke-Pearson DL: Comparing the Areas under
Two or More Correlated Receiver Operating Characteristic Curves: A Nonparametric Approach. Biometrics 1988,44:837-845.
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2531595

Comment: This example with a single point can be really misleading. For example, having point at (1, 0) will yield AUC=1 according to your calculations. Area under point is always zero.
If you really need to summarize the contingency table, use f1 score or informedness.

Comment: @PavelTyshevskyi The ROC curve is always a curve, never a single point. Remember it shows 1-specificity, which is probably what confuses you.

Comment: @PavelTyshevskyi I mean (1, 0) is actually 0 specificity 0 sensitivity, so the AUC will be 0 as expected.

Comment: You're right, I've got confused with the axis. It still doesn't sound right with (0, 0) and (1, 1) being used to construct an area together with se, sp from contingency matrix, somehow. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @PavelTyshevskyi can you be a bit more specific maybe? The answer is correct, and I think I clearly point out why you shouldn't do it in the first place. But I assure you, it is absolutely correct.

Comment: You're totally right, I misunderstood the geometric interpretation of AUC in your answer, sorry for the confusion.
There is a new article on this topic, I found it particularly interesting, you can add it to references:
Muschelli, J. ROC and AUC with a Binary Predictor: a Potentially Misleading Metric. J Classif (2019)

Comment: What a charming post! thanks for the good time and the info

Answer (score 2):

When I claim all of them are negative, then sensitivity (y) = 0, 1 - specificity (x) = 0. If I claim the positive/negative according to test results, then y =A/(A+C), x=B/(B+D). When I say all of them are Positive, then y = 1 and x = 1.

Based on three points with coordinate (0,0) (A/(A+C), B/(B+D)) (1,1), (in (y,x) order), it is easy to calculate the area under the curve by using the formula for area of triangle.

Final result: Area = $\frac {AB+2AD+2CD}{(A+C)(B+D)}$ ? Need to be verified.