# Create AUC-ROC from single sensitivity and specificity value?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, roc, sensitivity-specificity

Is it possible and appropriate to estimate the area under the receiver operating characteristic curve from a single point estimate of an individual's sensitivity and specificity performance?

Comment: For future viewers, this other stackoverflow answer offers a great answer to effectively the same question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372236/what-is-the-formula-to-calculate-the-area-under-the-roc-curve-from-a-contingency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOT REALLY**

That gives you one point (call it $(x,y)$) in the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Think about how many non-decreasing curves can go from $(0,0)$ to that $(x,y)$ point to $(1,1)$.

One curve could be a diagonal line from $(0,0)$ to your $(x,y)$ point and then another diagonal line from your $(x,y)$ point to $(1,1)$, while another could start the same way while curving up in a quarter-circle path from the $(x,y)$ point to $(1,1)$. These have different areas.

**EDIT**

“Estimate” is a strange term, because there is a sense in which fixed numbers can be acceptable estimators (technical term is “admissible”), even if they are independent of the data, and nothing even requires us to pick an admissible estimator. Thus, a lot of values could be estimators of AUC, and you are correct to point out in the comments that you get a lower bound of sensitivity times specificity. That’s probably a weak lower bound, weak enough to be worthless, but I suppose it’s a better lower bound than $1/2$ or zero.

(Consider the lower bound you get if sensitivity and specificity each are $0.7$.)

Comment: Agree that the more point estimates one has, the higher confidence one can get that the AUC is correct, but if the ROC is non-decreasing, than an estimate for a single point estimate would be a lower confidence estimate, and importantly only an underestimate. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @pw-314 Lower estimate of what?

Comment: A lower estimate as to what the AUROC would be if there were more data points available

Comment: You would get a lower bound, yes, by saying that you can’t do any worse than the curve that is zero until $horizontal=x$, then jumps up to $vertical=y$ to hit $(x,y)$, then continues at $vertical=y$ until $horizontal=1$, where the curve jumps up to $vertical=1$. The area under this curve would be $y(1-x)$, so sensitivity times specificity.